# Can a value from a JTextField be forced into the ValueModel (JGoodies)

Tags: java, binding, model, jgoodies

I have this code:

```
this.trigger = new Trigger();
this.presentationModel = new PresentationModel(this.personBean, this.trigger);
final ValueModel firstNameAdapter = presentationModel.getBufferedModel("firstName");
final JTextField firstNameTextField = BasicComponentFactory.createTextField(firstNameAdapter);
```

and

```
firstNameTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            trigger.triggerCommit();
        }
    });
```

So when I push the enter button on the `JTextField`, I expect the value in my `ValueModel` class to be the same as the value in my `JTextField`. This doesn't happen unless I click outside the `JTextField`, then back inside the `JTextField`, and then push enter. If I just type in the text and hit enter, the `ValueModel` does not get the updated value. I am stuck on this problem, can anybody help?

BTW, I used this link for figuring out JGoodies in the first place: [JGoodies Tutorial](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17728)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through the JGoodies API (should have done this sooner) and found an unexpected static call, Bindings.commitImmediately()

If I call this method before my call to trigger.triggerCommit(), everything works as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am understanding your question correctly.

You need to get the text in the text field and set it in the ValueModel.

```
firstNameTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener()      
{         
    @Override         
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)          
    {
       //this get the text from the text field
       String firstName = firstNameTextField.getText();

       //now write your code to set the firstname into the ValueModel


       trigger.triggerCommit();
    }     
 });
```

Comment: I could manually call the getter on the JTextField and the setter on the ValueModel, but that doesn't work so well if I am using ints, longs, or formatted data in my JTextField. There has to be a way to programmatically force the data from the JTextField into the ValueModel.

Comment: Well, if you were using ints, longs, or other formatted date you would just have to parse it.

Comment: True, I could make it work, but this can't be what the authors of JGoodies intended. I did send an email to them about this problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert on JGoodies, so after reading more about it I understand what your saying.

Answer (score 0):

Create a text field that commits on each key typed instead of when focus is lost:

```
BasicComponentFactory.createTextField(firstNameAdapter, false);
```

Also, you should consider architecting your program to not use buffered models.  I find that they make things more complicated and tricky, and think I saw Karsten Lentzsch recommending not to use them as well in a mailing list.

The most useful way for me to learn JGoodies was to look at the tutorial code for the JGoodies binding and validation libraries.